# Read files in a single expression, properly closing them

Tags: python, file, expression, list-comprehension, contextmanager

I want to read the content of a list of files in python. 
My first idea was

`contents = [open(f).read() for f in files]`

But that leaves the files open until the objects are garbage collected, and shows `ResourceWarning`.

Closing the files requires multiple comprehensions:

```
fds = [open(f) for f in files]
contents = [fd.read() for fd in fds]
[fd.close() for fd in fds]
```

...which is unnatural.

or a loop:

```
contents = []
for f in files:
    with open(f) as fd:
        contents.append(f.read())
```

...which is quite verbose, and long to read.

Is there any other alternative?

Comment: _But that leaves the files open until the objects are garbage collected_ - not true (mostly). In cpython, each file is closed as its ref count goes to 0 inside the generator. The garbage collector is not involved with deleting most objects - it only comes in play when ambiguous references keep the regular decref from realizing the object is "__del__"-able. Some alternate pythons don't decref the same, but for cpython I would personally be comfortable with your original one liner.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks for the context! By "garbage collected" here I meant general garbage collection, including reference counting, not just `gc`. Admittedly the term "garbage collection" is ambiguous when we're talking about cpython, and I agree that the examples work perfectly fine there. In my particular case, I know for sure I need to support non-cpython implementations. And in general, I think it's reasonable to write python as specified by the language, as opposed to the reference implementation

Comment: Yes, I can grudgingly agree. I am still stubborn in my belief that ref counting should be canonical. It wasn't until secondary (and nonconforming IMHO) implementations like jython came along that this was an issue. Your example is the exact reason why ref counts are good. Resource management is the number one problem with a language like C and python is supposed to solve that one.

Comment: @tdelaney when you say "nonconforming", do you mean that the language specification was changed when jython came along? I agree, it would definitely be nice to have the initial example "just work", but kichik's answer is even more explicit, in my opinion. I found the [pypy page discussing garbage collection differences](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html) very interesting

Comment: @goncaloop - I'm not sure how formal the specification was at the time - cpython is the reference implementation so in a sense whatever it happens to do is the specification. jython compiling to java bytecode has a different resource management model (other python implementations also) but its a bit of the tail wagging the dog to deprecate useful features because of them, IMHO. Python introduced cyclical garbage collection  to deal with ref count issues, but I certainly like the feature regardless of the risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for that.

```
from pathlib import Path
contents_text = [Path(f).read_text() for f in files]
contents_bytes = [Path(f).read_bytes() for f in files]
```

Inside it's just:

```
class Path:

    # ....

    def read_bytes(self):
        """
        Open the file in bytes mode, read it, and close the file.
        """
        with self.open(mode='rb') as f:
            return f.read()

    def read_text(self, encoding=None, errors=None):
        """
        Open the file in text mode, read it, and close the file.
        """
        with self.open(mode='r', encoding=encoding, errors=errors) as f:
            return f.read()
```

Comment: `pathlib` is quickly becoming one of my favorite modules. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ExitStack` context manager. Your use case is a slight variation on the example shown in the documentation.

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

with ExitStack() as es:
    contents = [es.enter_context(open(f)).read() for f in files]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function:

```
def read_contents(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        return file.read()

contents = [read_contents(f) for f in files]
```